# Multi User Licenses

Tags: sound-effects, library, licensing, multiple

Dear friends. 
As you may know, i´m running a sound fx company since about one year. www.thesoundcatcher.com
These days, the first time a customer asked for a 10 - multi-user license and i don´t really know how to handle this question. Should i sell my product 10 times to the client or should i make a special deal with him ?

How do you think about and what is a good way to handle this ?

regards Andreas

Answer (score 3):

Multi-user licenses are an excellent way of generating business.

We have to purchase 25 licenses each time, and there is rarely a discount.

I suggest a scale such as this: 5 licenses = 90% total cost, 10 = 80%, 25 = 70%, 50 = 60%, 100 = 50%

The increment does not have to be 10%, it could be 5%, or even 3%, but it would definitely be worth considering.

Comment: are these licenses limited to time ? Let´s say you pay a defined amount for a 1, 2, 3, 4..... year license ?

Comment: that would be impossible to track.  

Comment: I prefer licenses that are not limited by time,it is not about the cost, but the hassle of having to request and then organise the purchases.

Adobe has moved to subscriptions, which has mixed reception, http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/cs6/faq.edu.html

http://news.cnet.com/8301-1001_3-57586530-92/survey-creative-suite-users-loathe-adobes-subscriptions/





Answer (score 2):

Well, it's up to you of course. But from the point of view of the consumer, I think it's reasonable to expect some kind of discount for buying 10+ units. Perhaps you need to have a special rate for 5+, 10+, 25+ and quote a discount for them.

It's generally good to keep the customer happy. If you think you got a good deal somewhere you are much more likely to return.

Comment: i agree absolutely. I won´t sell my copy 10 times. They need a discount somehow but i want to figure out how much! 

Comment: Yeah, i guess that is the question. Looks like you'll also need a different license agreement for multi-user purchases. Worth looking over at Blastwave as they give you theirs: http://www.blastwavefx.com/i56/Multi---User-Licensing-Overview-&-Fee-Strucures/information.html   .No word on price though. Hopefully someone else will chime in here, as I'm no expert!

Answer (score 1):

Something else to keep in mind is the participation of lawyers in the sale. Depending on the "size" of the customer, it's entirely possible they will have a staff lawyer that will want to review, and possibly amend, your licensing agreement. If that happens, and you aren't confident in your understanding of the ramifications of those changes, you may want a lawyer of your own to represent your interests. That's something you'll want to factor into the cost of the sale.

Comment: I've had a lawyer for a big game company completely mark up and ammend our terms before agreeing to the sale.  we negotiated a bit before coming to an agreement. :)

Comment: Yep. I've heard a number of stories to that effect. ;)

Comment: Nearly every site license I do is a unique agreement tailored to the client. I have a standard agreement that I start with, but the lawyers usually have some terms they want to add/change, so there will almost always be negotiation.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, guys. Really helpfull. Let's see what the client says. Think i have to contact a lawyer for some purposes. 